# Delete Function using IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a delete function in ASP.NET MVC. I am not very sure on how to create a Delete function in ASP.NET.MVC using IHttpActionResult. There are error in `(sql)`,  `dBConnection.SubjectCodes.Remove(subjectCodeList);`
                    `dBConnection.SaveChanges();`.

The error stated that:

> DB Connection does not contain a definition for SubjectCodes

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using SubjectAPI.Models;

namespace SubjectAPI.Controllers
{

    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] 
        [RoutePrefix("api/Subject")]
        public class SubjectController : ApiController
        {
            public List<SubjectCode> SubjectCodes;

        [ActionName("DeleteSubject")]
            [Route("DeleteSubject")]
            public IHttpActionResult DeleteSubject(int Subject_Code_ID)
            {
                    DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
                    DataTable subjectCodeList = dBConnection.GetSqlDataTable(sql);                  

                    dBConnection.SubjectCodes.Remove(subjectCodeList);
                    dBConnection.SaveChanges();

                    return Ok(subjectCodeList);
            }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace SubjectAPI.Models
{
    public class SubjectCode
    {
        public int Class_Code_ID { get; set; }
    public string Subject_Code { get; set; }
        public string Subject_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Delete_Status { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: there's an error in the `(sql)`  and `dBConnection.SubjectCodes.Remove(subjectCodeList);`
                   ` dBConnection.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Is `DBConnection` your own class?

Answer (score 0):

The DeleteSubject method takes an `int Subject_Code_ID` as a parameter but it looks like you're trying to remove a `subjectCodeList`. Try getting the single subject code that matches the `Subject_Code_ID` and removing just that.

EDIT: I need to see the SubjectCode and DBConnection classes to give you a concrete example. Depending on how these work you might need something like:

```
DataTable subjectCodeList = dBConnection.GetSqlDataTable(sql);
var subjectCodeToDelete = subjectCodeList.Rows.Find(Subject_Code_ID);
if (subjectCodeToDelete == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
dBConnection.SubjectCodes.Remove(subjectCodeToDelete);
dBConnection.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: i need to have a `sql` statement right? Probably a `SELECT` Statement

Comment: I need to see you SubjectCode and DBConnection classes to be able to say for sure.

Comment: i've added SubjectCode and DBConnection

Comment: OK thanks, the error is right then - if that is your whole DBConnection class then it doesn't have any property called SubjectCodes. What version of MVC are you using? Is there any reason why you are using SqlConnections and DataTables instead of a DbContext? E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/

Comment: i'm using version 5

Comment: OK, unless there is a good reason for you to be using SqlConnection and DataTables I would recommend implementing entity framework functionality using a database context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-the-database-context